# What is the meaning of "include but not limited to"?

Tags: meaning

I have been following this trend for a while now , it seems to me it s very helpful to English learners like me . So far, I appreciate your contributions to questions. Below is my question for today:

> Responsibilities include but are not limited to: Effective operation of FLT equipment and palletisers.

Comment: This phrasing is the baneful legacy of legal language. It says that the list of responsibilities following the colon is not exhaustive. In other words, if you are negligent in some duty, you may not excuse yourself by saying that what you were  supposed to do isn't included in the list.

Comment: Thank you guys , very helpful , all clear now.

Answer (score 1):

As user105719 notes, the phrase has arisen due to people failing to understand, or looking for an excuse for their wilfully ignoring, an example.

The phrase you have quoted could be re-written as:

```
Responsibilities (for example, effective operation of FLT equipment and palletisers)
```

which means effectively the same thing.

However, by re-writing it as '... include but are not limited to: ...' it is more explicit, albeit perhaps less natural, that the item or items that follow are purely examples, and not intended to be a comprehensive list.

Hope that helps,

Alan.

Comment: Thank you guys , very helpful , all clear now.